# C++ heap memory performance improvement

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm writing a function where I need a significant amount of heap memory. Is it possible to tell the compiler that those data will be accessed frequently within a specific `for` loop, so as to improve performance (through compile options or similar)?

The reason I cannot use the stack is that the number of elements I need to store is big, and I get segmentation fault if I try to do it.

Right now the code is working but I think it could be faster.

UPDATE:
I'm doing something like this

```
vector< set<uint> > vec(node_vec.size());
for(uint i = 0; i < node_vec.size(); i++)
  for(uint j = i+1; j < node_vec.size(); j++)
    // some computation, basic math, store the result in variable x
      if( x > threshold ) {
         vec[i].insert(j);
         vec[j].insert(i);
      }
```

some details:
- I used hash_set, little improvement, beside the fact that hash_set is not available in all machines I have for simulation purposes
- I tried to allocate vec on the stack using arrays but, as I said, I might get segmentation fault if the number of elements is too big

If node_vec.size() is, say, equal to k, where k is of the order of a few thousands, I expect vec to be 4 or 5 times bigger than node_vec. With this order of magnitude the code appears to be slow, considering the fact that I have to run it many times.  Of course, I am using multithreading to parallelize these calls, but I can't get the function per se to run much faster than what I'm seeing right now.

Would it be possible, for example, to have vec allocated in the cache memory for fast data retrieval, or something similar?

Comment: What you think that can be optimized by the compiler? Memory is memory, there is no hardware difference between heap and stack. The access speed is based on usage pattern and the cache algorithm, but there is nothing the compiler can do about it.

Comment: Why not just use a allocator for the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
vector< set<uint> > vec(node_vec.size());
for(uint i = 0; i < node_vec.size(); i++)
  for(uint j = i+1; j < node_vec.size(); j++)
    // some computation, basic math, store the result in variable x
      if( x > threshold ) {
         vec[i].insert(j);
         vec[j].insert(i);
      }
```

That still doesn't show much, because we cannot know how often the condition `x > threshold` will be true. If `x > threshold` is very frequently true, then the `std::set` might be the bottleneck, because it has to do a dynamic memory allocation for every `uint` you insert.

Also we don't know what "some computation" actually means/does/is. If it does much, or does it in the wrong way that could be the bottleneck.

And we don't know how you need to access the result.

Anyway, on a hunch:

```
    vector<pair<int, int> > vec1;
    vector<pair<int, int> > vec2;

    for (uint i = 0; i < node_vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (uint j = i+1; j < node_vec.size(); j++)
        {
            // some computation, basic math, store the result in variable x
            if (x > threshold)
            {
                vec1.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
                vec2.push_back(make_pair(j, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you can use the result in that form, you're done. Otherwise you could do some post-processing. Just don't copy it into a `std::set` again (obviously). Try to stick to `std::vector<POD>`. E.g. you could build an index into the vectors like this:

```
    // ...
    vector<int> index1 = build_index(node_vec.size(), vec1);
    vector<int> index2 = build_index(node_vec.size(), vec2);
    // ...
}    

vector<int> build_index(size_t count, vector<pair<int, int> > const& vec)
{
    vector<int> index(count, -1);

    size_t i = vec.size();
    do
    {
        i--;
        assert(vec[i].first >= 0);
        assert(vec[i].first < count);
        index[vec[i].first] = i;
    }
    while (i != 0);

    return index;
}
```

ps.: I'm almost sure your loop is *not* memory-bound. Can't be sure though... if the "nodes" you're not showing us are really big it might still be.

---

Original answer:

There is no easy `I_will_access_this_frequently_so_make_it_fast(void* ptr, size_t len)`-kind-of solution.

You can do some things though.

1. Make sure the compiler can "see" the implementation of every function that's called inside critical loops. What is necessary for the compiler to be able to "see" the implementation depends on the compiler. There is one way to be sure though: define all relevant functions in the same translation unit *before* the loop, and declare them as `inline`.

   This also means you should *not* by any means call "external" functions in those critical loops. And by "external" functions I mean things like system-calls, runtime-library stuff or stuff implemented in a DLL/SO. Also don't call virtual functions and don't use function pointers. And or course don't allocate or free memory (inside the critical loops).
2. Make sure you use an optimal algorithm. Linear optimization is moot if the complexity of the algorithm is higher than necessary.
3. Use the smallest possible types. E.g. don't use `int` if `signed char` will do the job. That's something I wouldn't normally recommend, but when processing a large chunk of memory it can increase performance quite a lot. Especially in very tight loops.
4. If you're just copying or filling memory, use `memcpy` or `memset`. *Disable* the intrinsic version of those two functions if the chunks are larger then about 50 to 100 bytes.
5. Make sure you access the data in a cache-friendly manner. The optimum is "streaming" - i.e. accessing the memory with ascending or descending addresses. You can "jump" ahead some bytes at a time, but don't jump too far. The worst is random access to a big block of memory. E.g. if you have to work on a 2 dimensional matrix (like a bitmap image) where p[0] to p[1] is a step "to the right" (x + 1), make sure the inner loop increments x and the outer increments y. If you do it the other way around performance will be *much much* worse.
6. If your pointers are alias-free, you can tell the compiler (how that's done depends on the compiler). If you don't know what alias-free means I recommend searching the net and your compiler's documentation, since an explanation would be beyond the scope.
7. Use intrinsic SIMD instructions if appropriate.
8. Use explicit prefetch instructions if you know which memory locations will be needed in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm writing a function where I need a significant amount of heap memory ... will be accessed frequently within a specific for loop

This isn't something you can really optimize at a compiler level. I think your concern is that you have a lot of memory that may be "stale" (paged out) but at a particular point in time you will need to iterate over all of it, maybe several times and you don't want the memory pages to be paged out to disk.

You will need to investigate strategies that are platform specific to improve performance. Keeping the pages in memory can be achieved with [`mlockall`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mlockall.html) or [`VirtualLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895%28VS.85%29.aspx) but you really shouldn't need to do this. Make sure you know what the implications of locking your application's memory pages into RAM is, however. You're hogging memory from other processes.

You might also want to investigate a [low fragmentation heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366750(v=vs.85).aspx) (however it may not be relevant at all to this problem) and [this page](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) which describes cache lines with respect to `for` loops.

The latter page is about the nitty-gritty of how CPUs work (a detail you normally shouldn't have to be concerned with) with respect to memory access.

> Example 1: Memory accesses and performance
>   How much faster do you expect Loop 2 to run, compared Loop 1?
>
> ```
> int[] arr = new int[64 * 1024 * 1024];
>
> // Loop 1
> for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] *= 3;
>
> // Loop 2
> for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i += 16) arr[i] *= 3;
> ```
>
> The first loop multiplies every value in the array by 3, and the second loop multiplies only every 16-th. The **second loop only does about 6% of the work of the first loop**, but on modern machines, **the two for-loops take about the same time**: 80 and 78 ms respectively on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with compiler options. Depending on your usage (insertion, random-access, deleting, sorting, etc.), you could maybe get a better suited container.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can already see that the data is accessed frequently within the loop.

Comment: Not if the memory location is passed into to a third party library, and that third party library calls back to the main code with that memory location saying "here, do something with this!" The compiler has no knowledge of the potential memory locations the callback is being invoked with.

Comment: @taspeotis: Of course not. So what would be the point of telling it manually? It can't do anything about 3rd party code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only allocating the data from the heap once before doing the looping, note, as @lvella, that memory is memory and if it's accessed frequently it should be effectively cached during execution.